# Is it possible to implement printf() in a non blocking manner in linux terminal

Tags: c, linux, printing, terminal

I have a printf statement after sleep for 1 second. Since the printf statement takes longer than 1 second , the refresh rate is more than 2 seconds. Here is an example i am talking about :

```
while(1){
   printf("%s",buf);//Takes more than one second to print a table. Only few          
                    //values are updated
   sleep(1);
}
```

How can i have a printf to be non blocking. Is there a way in a standard linux machine ?

-Sanatan

Comment: `printf(...) ; flush(buf);` ? (Haven't done this in years, but search for proper use of `flush()`. (or `fflush()`?) Good luck.

Comment: @shellter How would doing a separate fflush() solve his problem? It wouldn't be faster and would still block.

Comment: @jforberg :   As I said, "haven't done this in years", AND this not what iI would describe as a perfectly written question, so I was just offering something to try until an answer from an expert appeared (sometimes they don't appear). Someone else seems to agree that is worth a try. Will gladly vote for answer below if it solves the O.P.s problem. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Fair enough, no offence meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only care about what shows on the screen, that is one of the problems that curses addresses.  Using curses, you could update the display using reasonably optimal output (only the changed areas would be updated rather than printing the whole table each time), and with the [typeahead](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-typeahead) feature, you can alleviate the problem of falling behind if the updates are too rapid.

It's more complicated than just `printf`.  But with `printf`, the buffer will get full, and there is nowhere to put it except to the standard output.  In some implementations, you *could* use `setvbuf` to assign a new output buffer, but POSIX frowns on that after output has started, [saying](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html):

> The `setvbuf()` function may be used after the stream pointed to by stream is associated with an open file but ***before*** any other operation (other than an unsuccessful call to `setvbuf()`) is performed on the stream.

Because of this, ncurses has treated `setvbuf` (and similar functions such as `setbuf`) with caution.  In the current release, to solve other problems, ncurses no longer uses this function.  But it is [still documented](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-NCURSES_NO_SETBUF):

> ncurses enabled buffered output during  terminal  initialization.   This  was  done (as in SVr4 curses) for performance reasons.  For testing purposes, both of ncurses  and
>   certain  applications,  this  feature  was  made optional.
>   Setting the  **`NCURSES_NO_SETBUF`**  variable  disabled  output
>   buffering,  leaving  the  output  in the original (usually
>   line buffered) mode.

Comment: I was just about to post an answer about ncurses, and here is the maintainer himself beating me to it :) It's a small internet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions . How does it compare to using another thread dedicated just to do printf operation.

Comment: printf could fall behind and have its buffer full :-)

Comment: Thanks ! I will look for an example to try.

Answer (score 0):

The function printf is a buffered function. It only flush to stdout when the buffer is full or when you force it. If you print a \n this will full the buffer. What you can do is to use the fflush function on stdout to force it.

Comment: I don't understand how this is relevant to the question. While unclear, the question didn't mention buffering at all and that does not seem to be his problem.